# Django Forms CheckboxInput on Y/N String field in existing database

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, modelform

I'm relatively new to Django, and I'm making a form which I'm connecting to a existing MySQL database.

What I'm trying to do is create a maintenance page for countries. One of the fields in my database is eu_member_state.

What I'm trying to do here is create a checkbox for this field, so I can uncheck it for the United Kingdom which recently got out of the EU.

```
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Countries
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'eu_member_state': forms.CheckboxInput()
        }
```

The checkbox does appear on my form, but how can I make this talk to my database? How can this checkbox only be checked when the database value is 'Y', and how do I write this back to my database on save, so 'Y' when checked and 'N' when unchecked?

This is the model code:

```
from django.db import models

class Countries(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=3)
    descr = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    descrshort = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    country_2char = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    eu_member_state = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=False, null=False, default='N')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'countries'
        verbose_name_plural = "countries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descr
```

Comment: Can you show us your models?

Comment: I've added the model to the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around it by creating a custom CheckboxInput field and initialise this in the forms.py.

```
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    eu_member_state_flag = forms.BooleanField(required=False,label='EU member state')

    class Meta():
        model = Countries
        exclude = ('eu_member_state',)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CountryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance.eu_member_state == "Y":
            flag_value = True
        else:
            flag_value = False

        self.initial['eu_member_state_flag'] = flag_value
```

Then in views.py I'm fetching the value of the CheckboxInput field and convert that into a 'Y' or a 'N'.

```
class UpdateCountryView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url= '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'tour_admin/countries_list.html'
    form_class = CountryForm
    model = Countries

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data

            if data['eu_member_state_flag']:
                data['eu_member_state'] = 'Y'
                self.object.eu_member_state = 'Y'
            else:
                data['eu_member_state'] = 'N'
                self.object.eu_member_state = 'N'
            self.object.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('countries_list')
```